# SQL sentence to name 3 id tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to get as a result of my query 3 tags name instead of getting the tag_id. This is the situation:

```
create table names (
 ˋattr_idˋ int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
 ˋattr_nameˋ varchar(30),
 primary key(ˋattr_idˋ)
) engine=MyISAM

create table posts (
 ˋpost_idˋ int(5) unsigned not null auto_increment
 ˋattr_1 int(11) unsigned,
 ˋattr_2ˋ int(11) unsigned,
 ˋattr_3ˋ int(11) unsigned,
 ˋreferencedˋ int(5),
 primary key (ˋpost_idˋ)
) engine=MyISAM

insert into names (ˋattr_nameˋ) values 
(''),('name1'),('name2'),('name3'),('name4'),('name5'),('name6');

insert into posts (ˋattr_1ˋ, ˋattr_2ˋ, ˋattr_3ˋ, referenced) values
(1, 2, 3, null), (1, 4, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 1), (4, 2, 5, 1)
```

The result I'm trying to obtain are the rows which `referenced` value is equal to the `post_id = 1` and for all these rows, change its `attr_1`, `attr_2` and `attr_3` for the `attr_name` which is in `names` table.

That's what I've tried before asking the question. Here I could get the post with `referenced` value equals 1:

```
SELECT post_id, attr_1, attr_2, attr_3, referenced
FROM posts
WHERE a.referenced = 1;
```

But here, trying to change the `name` insted of `attr_1` or `attr_2` or `attr_3` couldn't get what I wanted:

```
SELECT a.post_id, b.attr_name, b.attr_name, b.attr_name, a.referenced
FROM posts a, names b
WHERE a.referenced = 1 AND
      a.attr_1 = b.attr_id AND
      a.attr_2 = b.attr_id AND
      a.attr_3 = b.attr_id
GROUP BY a.post_id
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very efficient solution is to join the names table once for each attr_ like this:

```
SELECT p.post_id, n1.attr_name, n2.attr_name, n3.attr_name, p.referenced
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN names n1 ON p.attr_1 = n1.attr_id
LEFT JOIN names n2 ON p.attr_2 = n2.attr_id
LEFT JOIN names n3 ON p.attr_3 = n3.attr_id
WHERE p.referenced = 1
```

Given your sample data the output would be:

```
post_id attr_name       attr_name       attr_name   referenced
2                       name3           name1           1
4                       name1           name4           1
5       name3           name1           name4           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need left joins to get name of each value :

```
SELECT post_id,
       att1.attr_name,
       att2.attr_name,
       att3.attr_name,
       referenced
FROM   posts a
       LEFT JOIN names att1
              ON a.attr_1 = att1.attr_id
       LEFT JOIN names att2
              ON a.attr_2 = att2.attr_id
       LEFT JOIN names att3
              ON a.attr_3 = att3.attr_id
WHERE  a.referenced = 1;
```

left join will prevent omitting unmatched rows (if present).

Answer (score 0):

You should make 3 join, one for each attr value:

```
SELECT a.post_id, b1.attr_name, b2.attr_name, b3.attr_name, a.referenced
FROM posts a, names b1, names b2, names b3
WHERE a.referenced = 1 AND
      a.attr_1 = b1.attr_id AND
      a.attr_2 = b2.attr_id AND
      a.attr_3 = b3.attr_id
GROUP BY a.post_id
```

Comment: Please don't encourage pre-ANSI SQL-92 implicit joins... use explicit joins instead.